# Should there be a comma after "he added" if I'm not quoting?

Tags: commas

At my job we usually write something like this:

> Mr. Smith stated the defendant is welcome to stay at his residence and
>   may receive mail at that address, if necessary.  He added he is
>   willing to provide him with transportation to future court
>   proceedings, if needed.

There is only one editor that adds a comma after the word "added" and I believe it is unnecessary.

Comment: If he is implying a pause, he is free to add a comma there.

Comment: I find that it parses more easily with with the addition of "that": "Mr. Smith stated that the ... He added that"

Answer (score 3):

A comma?  If you were quoting Mr. Smith, a comma would be fine: "Mr. Smith stated, 'The defendant is welcome to stay at my residence'".  But since you are paraphrasing Mr. Smith, I would add "that" after "stated" and "added": "Mr. Smith stated that the ... He added that ..."

Answer (score 0):

As full stop is used for a 'pause'  in the same way comma is also used for a 'small pause'.

Your expression will be slightly different from what you are saying with and without comma.

So I think comma is OK in this case

Answer (score 0):

The rest of the sentence that follows "He added" is a direct object of "added." Therefore, no comma is needed.

Comment: The valid re-ordering << He is willing to provide him with transportation to future court proceedings if needed, he added. >> indicates that classing a report clause (possibly plus 'that' if postposed) as a direct object is not an obvious analysis. But hello, ajm.